# Using blocktrans with "with" and "count" keywords together

Tags: python, django, internationalization, pluralize

Is it possible to use `{% blocktrans %}` with "**with**" and "**count**" at the same time?

The documentation describes only the separate using:

```
{% blocktrans with foo|filter as bar and baz|filter as boo %}
{% blocktrans count var|length as count %}
```

I need to print a value of one variable, and the translation depends on another variable. I tried the following code:

```
{% blocktrans count cnt as count with cnt|make_text_from_count as text_count %}
    and other {{ text_count }} city
{% plural %}
    and other {{ text_count }} cities
{% endblocktrans %}
```

It displays the value of a `text_count` variable, but does not translate text.

Python 2.6.6, Django 1.3, django-templates.

Comment: The problem was in "fuzzy" flag inside .mo file.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to be careful with the order of the `blocktrans` arguments: `with` requires a local variable binding immediately after it, and `count` and its respective variable binding come after that.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) (for version 1.5 at least) has a couple of pluralization examples. The second example (introduced as "A more complex example") shows the order when both `with` and `count` are used:

```
{% blocktrans with amount=article.price count years=i.length %}
That will cost $ {{ amount }} per year.
{% plural %}
That will cost $ {{ amount }} per {{ years }} years.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

If you don't need any other variables than the one for the counter, do not use the keyword `with` at all. This is shown in the documented first example above the more complex one:

```
{% blocktrans count counter=list|length %}
There is only one {{ name }} object.
{% plural %}
There are {{ counter }} {{ name }} objects.
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#blocktrans-template-tag

```
{% blocktrans with text_count=cnt|make_text_from_count count cnt=cnt %}
    and another city
{% plural %}
    and other {{ text_count }} cities
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError: "'count' in u'blocktrans' tag expected exactly one keyword argument.". And if I fix it, then we obtain the equivalent of my code, but with a different syntax.

Comment: The singular case doesn't require {{ text_count }}, as text_count == 1 there.

Comment: I've edited my answer, after `count` django of course expects another keyword argument...